# Multithread Python with EC2

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a process that I have built to work in parallel using multiprocessing.Process within Python 2.7; it should work really fast in theory on an EC2 cluster with a ton of vCPU, but it isn't scaling as I expected. I'm running the code on a 96 vCPU machine (an m5.24xlarge instance), but while the function being parallelized runs in ~45 minutes on a 4 vCPU machine when being run on its own when I try and run 90 in parallel it takes 5+ hours for all of the sub-processes to finish.

I've considered using the Pool function to get away from the batching that occurs, but the function being called runs ~200 models that can really run a long time (and sometimes get stuck in weird optimization loops) so I have an additional process running in the background that will start sending soft Ctrl+C commands to the sub-process once it has 3 hours of processor time behind it every 10 minutes to ensure processing for any individual subprocess does not go on too long.

Each vCPU running a sub-process ranges between 40 and 99% utilized until the subprocess completes. My question, why does multiprocessing not linearly scale when moving to a bigger instance? I keep 5 vCPU available to run any background processes, so it isn't being bogged down there.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import datetime
import Prod_Modeling_Pipeline as PMP
import boto3
import pandas
import time
import numpy
import os

#Define locations
bucketName = 'bucketgoeshere'
output_location = '/home/ec2-user/'

#Pull ATM Setter Over
client = boto3.client('s3')
transfer = boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer(client=client)
transfer.download_file(bucketName,'Root_Folder/Control_Files/'+'execution_file.csv', output_location+'execution_file.csv')

#Read-in id list
execution_data = pandas.read_csv(output_location+'execution_file.csv')
ids = execution_data['id']

ni = 90
id_row = [['AAA']*ni for _ in xrange(int(numpy.ceil(len(tids)/float(ni))))]

for i in xrange(len(ids)):
    id_row[i/ni][i%ni] = ids[i]

Date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

totalstart = time.time()
for q in xrange(len(tid_row)):
    processes = []
    for m in xrange(len(tid_row[q])):
        temp = tid_row[q]
        try:
            p = Process(target=PMP.Model_Function, args=(temp[m],Date,'VALIDATION'))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Started "+temp[m]+" as "+str(os.getpid()))
        except:
            print("Invalid Run")

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(processes)

print (time.time() - totalstart)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now why it isn't linearly scaling. It all comes down to clock speed between a t2 EC2 instance and a m EC2 instance. Max clock speed is much higher for the smaller instances... up to 3.3 GHz for small t2s and 2.5 GHz for m type instances.

(https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

That will limit scale-ability when you change to the larger instance type because you moved to a slower max clock speed.

This isn't all of my above problem, but it explains a portion of the time increase.

Another portion appears to be due using a shared processor so that even though the EC2 should take less time, someone else in my org is hogging processing power. Unsure how to fix that under corporate constraints.